# Class extension in Python like in Swift?

Tags: python, swift, class, extension-methods

I am new to Python, coming from Swift, and I am wondering about the following. In Swift, if I would like to add functionality to an existing class, I can do something like this (as in the book example):

```swift
extension Double {
    var km: Double { return self * 1_000.0 }
    var m: Double { return self }
    var cm: Double { return self / 100.0 }
    var mm: Double { return self / 1_000.0 }
    var ft: Double { return self / 3.28084 }
}
let oneInch = 25.4.mm
```

I really like this functionality and I was wondering if there is something similar in Python. Or if there is some other way much better that I do not see and hence this does not make any sense in Python.

Comment: To extend functionality of a class in Python, you usually create a new class which inherits from the one you want to extend.

Comment: This wouldn't even be appropriate Swift. Your code assumes that Doubles are in metres, which is really easy to overlook, and will cause bugs. It's better to use a class like `NSMeasurement`, or equivalent.

Comment: @kabanus so there's not much extension going on in python other than on your own classes?

Comment: @kabanus Yikes. But I disagree with your conclusion on not extending built-in types. That's practically the main point of extensions. If it were just about user types, you could conceivably just write all your extensions in the main type declaration. Having functions like `isEven`, `isPrime`, `squared`, `isNaN`, etc. is incredibly invaluable. Let alone the benefits of retroactively adding protocol conformances, so that you don't waste your type writing `IntWrapper`, `DoubleWrapper`, etc. as you would in other languages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I think this is what you should do (In Swift as well!):

```
class Meter(float):
    def to_km(self): return self * 1000.0 
    def to_m (self): return self 
    def to_cm(self): return self / 100.0 
    def to_mm(self): return self / 1000.0 
    def to_ft(self): return self / 3.28084 

oneInch = Meter(25.4).to_mm()
print(oneInch)
```

Make it clear that your object represents a meter, and that you are converting it to something.

If you want some syntactic sugar, **that I am not sure is helpful**, you can override the item getter so you do not have to use `()`:

```
class Meter(float):
    conversions = {
        'km':1000,
        'cm':.01,
        'mm':.001,
        'ft':1/3.28084
    }
    def __getattr__(self,x):
        try:
            return self*Meter.conversions[x]
        except KeyError:
            raise KeyError("No such conversion!")

oneInch = Meter(25.4).mm
print(oneInch)
```

Adding conversions is as simple as:

```
Meter.conversions['whatever'] = 123.123
```

Comment: i think my example might not be the best, but your answer is really close to what I am looking for, is there a way to change your code so that I can do oneInch = 25.to_mm or at least oneInch = Meter(25.4).to_mm?

Comment: python way looks cumbersome

Comment: Just use a `property` instead of overriding `__getattr__`

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't extend builtin classes like `float` or `int`.

```
>>> int.double = lambda self: self * 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'int'
```

(You can modify non-builtin classes though, but you really *shouldn't*, as code doing that is hard to reason about.)

Your particular example is better served by an unit library like [`pint`](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) -- using libraries like that prevents you from making [$125 million mistakes doing math between metric and imperial units](http://mentalfloss.com/article/25845/quick-6-six-unit-conversion-disasters), too.

Answer (score 1):

You can build child classes of parent classes.  If you're writing your own code, sometimes this is a good idea, but extending something like a pandas dataframe is probably a bad idea

I didn't spend much time googling for you, but this is the best I found: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

This is also some really bad code I wrote trying to explain class inheritance to my girlfriend.  Note that the `Car` class will still have `car.roll_up_windows()` and `car.roll_down_windows()` and the `__repr__`:

```
class Plant(object):
    def __init__(self, color, seeds):
        self.color = color
        self.seeds = seeds

class Fruit(Plant):
    def __init__(self, color, defense):
        self.color = color
        self.seeds = True
        self.defense = defense

class Vehicle(object):
    def __init__(self, num_tires, engine_size, fuel_type):
        self.num_tires = num_tires
        self.engine_size = engine_size
        self.fuel_type = fuel_type
        self.windows = 'up'

    def roll_down_windows(self):
        self.windows = 'down'
    def roll_up_windows(self):
        self.windows = 'up'

    def __repr__(self):
        print("This is a vehicle. \nIt has {} tires. \nIts engine has {} liters. \nIt runs on {}. \nIt's windows are {}.".format(self.num_tires, self.engine_size, self.fuel_type, self.windows))

class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, num_tires=4, engine_size, fuel_type):
        self.num_tires = num_tires
        self.engine_size = engine_size
        self.fuel_type = fuel_type
        self.windows = 'up'
```

Comment: I am getting the feeling that there are not that many class extensions in python, other than on your own classes